# Erro ao tentar cadastrar sistema CRUD asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando fazer um Crud com asp.net MVC, já criei as Views, mas quando clico no botão Create recebo essa informação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue minhas classes:
Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CadastroTarefas2.Models
{
    public class Tarefas
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome da tarefa.")]
        public string nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a descrição da tarefa.")]
        public string descricao { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a data/prazo de entrega da tarefa.")]
        public DateTime data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CadastroTarefas2.Models;
using CadastroTarefas2.repositorio;

namespace CadastroTarefas2.Controllers
{
    public class TarefasController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Tarefas
        private TarefaRepositorio tarefaRepositorio;


        public ActionResult ObterTarefas()
        {
            tarefaRepositorio = new TarefaRepositorio();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(tarefaRepositorio.ObterTarefas());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult IncluirTarefa()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult IncluirTarefa(Tarefas tarefa)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    tarefaRepositorio = new TarefaRepositorio();
                    if (tarefaRepositorio.AdicionarTarefa(tarefa))
                    {
                        ViewBag.Mensagem = "Tarefa cadastrada com sucesso";
                    }
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("ObterTarefas");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EditarTarefa(int id)
        {
            tarefaRepositorio = new TarefaRepositorio();
            return View(tarefaRepositorio.ObterTarefas().Find(t => t.ID == id));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditarTarefa(int id, Tarefas tarefa)
        {
            try
            {
                tarefaRepositorio = new TarefaRepositorio();
                tarefaRepositorio.AtualizarTarefa(tarefa);
                return RedirectToAction("ObterTarefas");
            } catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("ObterTarefas");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult ExcluirTarefa(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                tarefaRepositorio = new TarefaRepositorio();
                if (tarefaRepositorio.ExcluirTarefa(id))
                {
                    //ViewBag.Mensagem = "Tarefa excluida com sucesso";
                }
                return RedirectToAction("ObterTarefas");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("ObterTarefas");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Views criadas automaticamente pelo Visual Studio 2019:
**ObterTarefas.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<CadastroTarefas2.Models.Tarefas>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.descricao)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.data)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.descricao)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.data)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**IncluirTarefa.cshtml**

```
@model CadastroTarefas2.Models.Tarefas

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Tarefas</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.data, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.data, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

EditarTarefa.cshtml

```
@model CadastroTarefas2.Models.Tarefas

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Tarefas</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.data, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.data, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.data, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Estou usando o SQL Server 2017 e estou conseguindo acessar o banco normalmente consigo adicionar os dados no banco e visualizar usando a view **ObterTarefas**. Agora as outras views não estão funcionando ainda.

Comment: já verificou se o objeto é nulo antes de tentar fazer um foreach nele?

Comment: Eu coloquei um if pra verificar se é nulo, agora ele não apresenta o erro, mas quando tento incluir os dados, ele não inclui, não da erro mas não adiciona informação na lista. Como posso resolver isso?